# Do-while зависает в Qt

Tags: c++, qtcreator, while

Помогите пожалуйста с одним вопросом. Пишу программу в Qt с интерфейсом. При нажатии кнопки должны выполняться определенные действия, на некоторые значения стоит проверка и QInputDialog для изменения значения во время выполнения программы. Написали конструкцию do-while для проверки, при некорректном вводе значения программа работает исправно снова предлагая ввести корректное значение, однако когда ввожу требуемое значение, то программа просто зависает и перестает работать. Не пойму почему, при использовании точно такой же конструкции, но в консольном приложении все работает исправно. Пожалуйста подскажите как решить эту проблему.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QLocale::setDefault(QLocale::C);
....
bool bv_1 = true;
bool ok;

do
{
    if (ver_1 < 0 || ver_1 > 1)
    {
        double test = QInputDialog::getDouble(this, "Ошибка ввода!", "Недопустимая вероятность смерти. Введите число от 0 до 1!", ver_1, -2147483647, 2147483647, 3, &ok );
        if (ok)
        {
            ver_1 = test;

        }
        else {
            bv_1 = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}while(bv_1);  ....}
```

Comment: Во-первых, чему равно начальное значение `ver_1 `??? Почему этой информации нет в вопросе? Во-вторых, при вводе значения между `0` и `1` вы получаете бесконечный цикл, как и написано у вас в коде.

Comment: Это десятичное число, которое вводится в форму, проблема явно не в нем, т.к. без цикла все работало исправно. И при использовании точно этого же цикла, но в консольном приложении - все работало нормально. Поэтому я даже не рассматривал что ошибка там

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что единственная возможность выйти из цикла - это попадание в ветку `if(ok)… else`. Так что цикл надо прерывать при успешной проверке числа:

```
while((ver_1 < 0) or (1 < ver_1))
{
    double test = QInputDialog::getDouble(this, "Ошибка ввода!", "Недопустимая вероятность смерти. Введите число от 0 до 1!", ver_1, -2147483647, 2147483647, 3, &ok );
    if(ok)
    {
        ver_1 = test;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло. Как-то сам не додумался до такого